# Python tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile - get file path

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, savefiledialog

I want to get path of file "exportFile".

```
exportFile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='a')
```

If I write "print exportFile", I get:

```
<open file u'C:/Users/Desktop/Test/aaaa.txt', mode 'a' at 0x02CB6078>
```

But I need only path - "C:/Users/Desktop/Test/aaaa.txt".
Is there any solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
exportFile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='a')
exportFile.name
```

It'll return:

```
'C:/Users/Desktop/Test/aaaa.txt'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm) instead of `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile`.

**NOTE** `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename` does not take `mode` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tkFileDialog.askdirectory` instead of any file name dialog.  That will return a directory instead of a file name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing 'exportFile' try to print 'exportFile.name'. It should give the output you desire