# Invalid file Save Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, savefiledialog

I'm trying to write a script that allows a user to create a folder with any name they want, and then create a file with any name they want. Once they do they, the program asks them for 3 names and writes them into the file. I then want to allow the user to input a number from 1 to 3 and display the number of lines they want. I'm getting an error right now when trying to read the file saying something along the lines of

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:blah blah ' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>
```

The code is below:

```
def SaveDir():
    global FileSave
    FileSave = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='a', defaultextension=".txt")
    if FileSave is None:                                                                                                                                          
        return
    print(FileSave)
    SaveDir2()

def SaveDir2():
    FinalFile = open(FileSave)
    FinalFile.write(PRINTCONV)
    FinalFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [`tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile`](http://pydoc.org/2.2.3/tkFileDialog.html#-askopenfile) returns the actual open file, which is why you got a `TypeEror` as that is not a valid file name that can be opened.  Consider using `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename` instead.  Alternatively just simply call `FileSave.write` as that *is* the open file object.

Similar questions have been asked before:

- [Python tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile - get file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877216/python-tkfiledialog-asksaveasfile-get-file-path)
- [Save File Dialog in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476232/save-file-dialog-in-tkinter)
- [Get file path from askopenfilename function in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373288/get-file-path-from-askopenfilename-function-in-tkinter)